# How can I change .toFixed() base on the decimals on the value?

Tags: javascript

I would like to show the value of a decimal number, including the last two(or any) visible digit (next to 0s).

Here are the examples I would like to archive:

```
Input: 1
Output: 1

Input: 0.1
Output: 0.1

Input: 0.000123
Output: 0.00012 //stripped down the "3", only show nearest 2 digits (12)

Input: 0.00102
Output: 0.0010 //stripped down the "2", only show nearest 2 digits (10)

Input: 0.000000100000000000000009999
Output: 0.00000010
```

I have tried to hard code it, but I don't think its that reliable. Is there a better way to do it?

```
function strip(val, length){
    var val = val.toString()
    var integer = val.split(".")[0]
    var decimals = val.split(".")[1]
    var reachedFirstDec = false
    var count = 0
    var result = ""
    var i = 0
    while (count !== length) {

        if (reachedFirstDec) {
            count++
        }

        if (decimals[i] !== "0" && !reachedFirstDec) {
            console.log(`Reached first non 0 character at ${i}`)
            reachedFirstDec = true
            count++
        }
        result = result + decimals[i]
        i++
        console.log(result);
    }
    return parseFloat(integer + "." + result)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the logarithm of ten of the number and adjust `toString` by one for getting the wanted result.

For a dynamic lenght, you could use a closure over the wanted lenght of the digits.

```js
function x(l) {
    return function (v) {
        var e = Math.floor(Math.log10(v));
        return e < 0 ? v.toFixed(l - 1 - e) : v;
    }
}

var array = [1000, 1, 0.1, 0.0001232456, 0.0010234567, 0.000000100000000000000009999];

console.log(array.map(x(2)));
console.log(array.map(x(3)));
console.log(array.map(x(4)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, would it be possible to have "dynamic" length other than 2? (like my ugly example above), eg (length=3): 0.001034 = 0.00103?